# Tables not showing divs and loop/php items

Tags: php, loop, page-template, blog-page

I know this is an absurd questions, as who uses tables anymore? I got handed this and just need to make it work really. I don't know anything about tables so it's been a learning experience.

I finally got my loop to show up but only parts of it. I'm missing some crucial items and can't figure it out.

Example: post title shows up but its not a hyperlink.

I tried to put these in the post but they broke terribly so I used pastebin. I guess cause the tables? lol

blog.php can be viewed here:

http://pastebin.com/fYyhGMYa

Live version:

http://elite.ikvclients.com/blog/

Really appreciate any insight or help. This is confusing as hell.

Comment: Generally speaking , it helps to post clean readable code, no one likes to read spaghetti, take a moment and format it.

Comment: Slight clean up.. I really don't know how to format the tables so I just tried to line some things up really. The word wrap is still making it slightly messy. http://pastebin.com/fYyhGMYa

Answer (score 0):

In your page template line 42 you will see

`<?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : //display excerpts for archives and search. ?>
                                                                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                            <?php else : ?>
                                                                            <?php the_content('Read More'); ?>
                                                            <?php endif; ?>`

This means that there won't be a heading on archive pages and the_excerpt doesn't allow html like hyperlinks (though you could use a plugin "advanced excerpt" to achieve formatting in excerpts)

Comment: Not an archive page but I removed it anyway to test and no changes appeared.